# Navigating to database selector page even after setting list_db = False in odoo 12

Tags: postgresql, odoo, ubuntu-server

I am trying to run another odoo instance on my ubuntu server.Now, in order to hide the database selector page, i have set **list_db = False** and **db_filter=mydb_name**. Now when run it and try to go to my_ip_address:8070 (xmlrpc_port=8070), it is navigating to database selector page and it says **The database manager has been disabled by the administrator**. How do i fix this? This is my conf file.

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = proadmin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoonew
db_password = False
addons_path =/opt/odoo/myerp/odoo/addons/,/opt/odoo/myerp/custom_addons/
log_level = info
logfile = /var/log/odoo/myerp-server.log
log_handler = ["[':INFO']"]
xmlrpc_port = 8070
db_filter = odooerp
list_db = False
```

and my service to run the instance,

```
[Unit]
Description=Odoo12 for myerp
Requires=postgresql.service
After=network.target postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
SyslogIdentifier=odoonew
PermissionsStartOnly=true
User=odoonew
Group=odoonew
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.7 /opt/odoo/myerp/odoo/odoo-bin -c /opt/odoo/myerp/myerp-odoo.conf
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Try to login as youre_ip_address:8012/web/login

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link [**https://github.com/Yenthe666/auto_backup/issues/67**][1]

Check it

When you set list_db as True odoo won't shows it and you can access your db as

> youre_ip_address:8012/web/login